# ElementTree findall() never finds the first child

Tags: python, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have an issue with XML parsing with element tree, I want to parse that file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Metrics xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://standards.iso.org/iso-iec/19086/-2/ed-1/en">
    <Metric description="CloudServiceAvailability" source="example" id="M_AVL_002" scale="RATIO">
        <Parameter id="P_001" parameterStatement="2.592 x10^6" unit="second"
            note="Parameter represents a 30 day billing cycle in seconds"/>
        <Expression id = "E_001" expressionStatement=" 100 x (P_001- M_TQD_001)/P_001" expressionLanguage="ISO80000" unit="percentage"/>
        <UnderlyingMetricRef refid="M_TQD_001"/>
    </Metric>
    <Metric description="TotalQualifiedDowntime" source="example" id="M_TQD_001" scale="RATIO" >
        <Expression id="E_001" expressionStatement="&#x3A3;(M_QDT_001)" expressionLanguage="ISO80000" unit="second"/>
        <UnderlyingMetricRef refid="M_QDT_001"/>
    </Metric>
</Metrics>
```

Here is my code:

```
for metric in root.findall('Metric'):
    print("COUCOU1")
    paramsTable=[]
    rulesTable=[]
    expressionsTable=[]
    metricTable={}
    metricTable['id']=metric.get('id')
    metricTable['desc']=metric.get('description')
```

The problem is that my program never gets in the loop. I have read all the related topics and tried:

```
root.findall('.//Metric')
root.findall('./Metric')
root.findall('Metrics/Metric')
```

but nothing worked I don't know what is going wrong!

EDIT : This question is different from the other because of the XML file Structure

Comment: It's because the XML has a default namespace. See https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces

Comment: Wow thank yo i would never have found ! maybe you could write a more detailed answer that i can accept as a solution for next users ?